# Iterating over the return value of an HTTPService .subscribe()

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs

I have an HttpService get request that I'm subscribing to, like so:

```
this.httpClient.get("/application/v1/sql-table").subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(Array.isArray(data), typeof data, data);
    });
```

I'm able to log the returned data just fine. It shows as an array of objects on the web console. I can even log a specific index, like `data[1]`. The second log statement returns some results in line with what I'm expecting, at least on Firefox: `true object Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]`

However, when I try to interact with this object as though it's an array, I hit a wall. I can't access `length`, use constructions like `for ... of`, or array functions like `forEach()`:

```
    (data) => {
        console.log(Array.isArray(data), typeof data, data);
        for (let item of data) {
            console.log(item);
        }
    }
```

---

```
ERROR in src/app/data.service.ts:111:27 - error TS2488: Type 'Object' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

111                     for (let item of data) {
```

How can I iterate over what's being returned here?

Comment: in your `tsconfig`, are your `lib` and `target` consistent? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12707

Comment: Wow, there it is! I had es2015 and es2018. Bringing both values to es2018 instantly fixed the issue. Thank you. If you'd like, post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is mentioned in the following GitHub issue.

The solution is to ensure that `target` and `lib` values are consistent in your `tsconfig` file.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12707